# Node JS - load HTML page from fetch API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to use the fetch API to send data to my nodeJS backend server from the front end. The backend then returns a webpage (renders a view), and I catch it using .then() after fetch.

How can I load the html page (response from the nodeJS backend) after receiving it? After some research, I found that one method to doing this is using .text(), but it doesn't seem to load the new page for me.

Router file (JS)

```js
router.get("/testPost", (req, res) => {
    res.render("test2");
});

router.post("/testPost", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render("test3");
    console.log("rendered?");
});
```

test2.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        function runCode() {
            weight = true
            data = { weight }
            fetch("/input/testPost", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                res.text();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="runCode()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test3.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Loaded</title>
</head>
<body>
    Page loaded
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.
But what is the point of making such solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        function runCode() {
            weight = true
            data = { weight }
            fetch("/input/testPost", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
            .then((res) => res.text())
            .then((res) => {
                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = res;

                document.body.appendChild(div);

                // if needed full page update
                document.body.innerHTML = res;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="runCode()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```